# JQuery - reset toggle state

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I have a button which when toggled displays/hides a div ('.reportOptions'), this works perfectly fine.

```
$('.reportOptions').click(function(e){ 
   e.stopPropagation();
});


$('.requestOptions').toggle(
   function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.reportOptions').css('display','block');   //show request options
   },function(){
      $('.reportOptions').css('display','none');    //hide all request oprtions menus
   }
);
```

the same div can also be hidden by clicking away from it by doing the following

```
$(document).click(function(){
   $('.reportOptions').css('display','none');
   $('.requestOptions').toggle(even);
});
```

the problem I have with the last function is that if it is performed I must double click the resuestOptions button in order to display the div again.

What I want to know is if there is any way in which you can reset the toggle state without having to change the toggle function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for jQuery's toggle method: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You may also want to take a moment to read through it further as there are show() and hide() methods. You should not be using css('display','none') to show and hide elements as the show and hide methods will handle all of that for you and it's much less confusing when you read your code.

I think you may have overthought this situation a bit. Try this instead:

```
$('.reportOptions').click(function(e){ 
   e.stopPropagation();
});


$('.requestOptions').click(
   function(e){
      $(this).parent().find('.reportOptions').show();   //show request options
      $('.requestOptions').hide();    //hide all request oprtions menus
      e.stopPropagation();
   }
);


$(document).click(function(){
   $('.reportOptions').hide();
   $('.requestOptions').show();
});
```

Basically you're binding a click function to the button that shows the div and hides the button and a click function to the document which hides the div and shows the button. The clicks on the button and the div stop propagation (which is what you were missing in the button before) so that the document click handler doesn't fire when those elements were clicked.

Comment: This would not work, I think you may have understood my question, but thanks for the attempt anyway

Comment: Admittedly it was a little hard to understand what you were trying to do between your code and your description. Can you be a little more specific about "This would not work"? If I don't know what you're trying to do or what didn't work, I can't very well help you :P

Comment: well the second function that you wrote has a contradiction, your showing and then hiding the .reportOptions div, what I basically want to do is let the toggle function know that .reportOptions div has been closed because at the moment the last function does not do this and so this means i have to double click on the toggle button after performing the last function.

Comment: anyway i just wanted to know if there was a way to do what i wanted without changing the toggle function in to a click, if there isn't then thats fine I think I can live with that.

Comment: Well you're looking to implement 2 functions. 1) When you click the button, the div shows up and the button hides. 2) When the div is shown and you click on the page, the div hides and the button shows. So what I'm doing is just that. The only missing link is that you need to stopPropagation() on the button and div clicks. You were only doing it on the div, not the button. So what was actually happening when you clicked the button is that the button was showing the div then the click event propagated to the document where the div was hidden again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the CSS directly, add a class name (and define it in your CSS). Then just remove the class name to revert back to normal.